# Adding and removing elements to/from the list (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, input, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have two list:

1. list with alredy exist cities
2. list from which I can add new cities to my first list.

If I type name it's OK, it is creating new item in first list. What I want to rich is adding cities to the first list by click on the elements from the second list (first check one city and then confirm action by pressing button).
A tried to get name of the clicked element via jQuery and put it into input, so to be able in the next step to confirm adding.

```
$(document).on('click', '.city', function () {
    var input = $('.city-input'),
        inputValue = input.val();
    input.val($(this).text());
    return false;
});
```

And it takes the name, and it puts this name into the input. But when I'm pressing button - it creates only empty element...

If I've typed something, then press button - it creates an element. Then if I press any city from second list - it appears in the input field, but after I press confirmation button it creates element with previous typed text...

Also, I've tried to create directive, but this still doesn't work..

```
addCityApp.directive('searchList', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            searchModel: '=model'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', attrs.searchList, function(){
                scope.searchModel = $(this).text();
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Here is my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyJuarez/yxtwhos6/)

Comment: Please try to avoid mixing JQuery and angular.  Instead of using the JQuery, just move that logic into an angular `ng-click="myFunction"` and define the `myFunction = function () {...}` in your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code using pure angular, here is the code:   http://jsfiddle.net/yxtwhos6/25/

```
$scope.setCity = function(city) { $scope.newItemName = city;};
```

I tried to change your code as least as I can.

Answer (score 1):

I would only use angular and set a model, here are my example: http://jsfiddle.net/yxtwhos6/16/

```
$scope.ultiCTRL = { selectedCity: '' };
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, sir. Your answer is definitely works good! But I chose the Shaohao's answer.